# Postgresql Full text search for numbers preceeded by hashsign

Tags: database, postgresql, search, full-text-indexing

The documents that I want to run full text search on contains sequences of a hash sign followed by a series of digits e.g. #12345 #9999. None of the parsers seem to recognize the sequence as a single token.

The blank parser does recognize '#' as a token, so I thought I could use a synonym dictionary to match '#' with 'num' and then use the follows operator e.g. # <-> 1234. However; the blank parser groups all the blank character into one token so the token usually contains a leading space ' #'. I can't make a synonym entry with a leading space (or at least don't know how to).

If I included the english_stem dictionary in the mapping for the blank parser then ' #' is recognized as a lexeme. But so are all the other blank characters which adds too much noise to the generated ts_vector

Short of creating a custom parser is there anyway I can configure the search so that I can use full text search to query explicitly for #0000 patterns?